# Error al crear nuevo proyecto Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Acabo de crear un nuevo proyecto **Android** con **Android Studio** he elegido el mínimo SDK que sea el **9 (Gingerbread)** y la actividad que sea un `NavigationDrawer Activity`, una vez elegido y creado el proyecto me sale el siguiente error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] C:\xxx\xxx\.android\build-cache\bd439271136a9bc6f4bc228104359605401bab70\output\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.design" to force usage
```

Y no he tocado nada ni he modificado nada de lo que ha creado el propio Android Studio y además tengo actualizado el SDK con las ultimas versiones.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

**EDIT: gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xx.xx.seguros"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Pública lo que tienes en el gradle de la app

Comment: @Einer ya lo he editado

Comment: Sube el minSdkVersion a 14 o, si no quieres hacer eso, utiliza otra versión de librería, la 25 por ejemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En cuanto al mensaje:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller
>   than version 14 declared in library
>   [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1]
>   C:\xxx\xxx.android\build-cache\bd439271136a9bc6f4bc228104359605401bab70\output\AndroidManifest.xml

Sugiere que al menos tengas definido un `minSdkVersion` version 14, ya que un elemento, en este caso la library de soporte para diseño ('com.android.support:design:26.+') requiere esta versión como mínimo para funcionar correctamente, una opción es cambiar a:

```
minSdkVersion 14
```

otra opción es regresar a las version 25 que la library de soporte para diseño ('com.android.support:design:25.0.0') puede trabajar con minSdkVersion 9

---

Como sugiere el mensaje puedes agregar en tu AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.design"/>
```

esto para obligar a que funcione con API Level 9 pero aunque funcione, notaras en dispositivos de esa versión o menores a API 14 comportamientos extraños por ejemplo:

`CardViews` con esquinas redondeadas en un dispositivo 2.3 se mostrarán solo cuadrados, no se mostrará la elevación.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Son las opciones que estaba barajando pero como dices es mejor bajarlo a 25

Comment: Hola @Joacer de hecho no había notado era una pregunta tuya hehe, realmente yo haría lo mismo. Yo realizaría lo mismo aunque, realmente aún así no te escapas de otros "detallitos" que se notan en la UI al usar la design support library en dispositivos menores a API 14 (Android 3.0). Te comento, proyectos que estamos realizando actualmente y que son actualizaciones decidimos por lo mismo tener un minSdkVersion 15, pero claro depende de los dispositivos que pretendas soportar con tu aplicación, el porcentaje de usuarios en nuestro caso con OS > 3.0 es 0.8% por eso esta decisión ...

Answer (score 4):

He encontrado dos soluciones para eliminar este error, pero no se cual será la más correcta

**I)** bajando la versión, para ello hay que modificar el build.gradle utilizando la versión 25 en vez de la 26 de la siguiente forma:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xx.xx.seguros"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**II)** utilizando `tools:overrideLibrary`, para ello hay que modificar el manifest añadiendo lo siguiente:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="es.uv.lisitt.seguros"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.design, android.support.v7.appcompat,android.support.graphics.drawable, android.support.v7.recyclerview, android.support.v4, android.support.mediacompat, android.support.fragment, android.support.coreui, android.support.coreutils, android.support.compat"/>

     .....
</manifest>
```

Comment: La otra opción es subir el atributo minSdkVersion a la 14, funcionará para Android 4.0 y superiores y así puede utilizar la librería que quería sin hacer nada más.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano esa opción también  la había contemplado, pero por exigencias del cliente quiere que sea compatible con versiones anteriores, por eso buscaba cómo solucionar el problema. Gracias!

Comment: Ok ok, entonces tus 2 soluciones son las que hay. Recuerda poner eso en el enunciado de la pregunta ya que no lo pone, por eso te sugería cambiar el minSdkVersion. Un saludo

Comment: si, de momento son las que he encontrado, aparte de la que has comentado, pero no se cual de las dos será la más correcta, ¿@PabloSimonDiEstefano tu que opinas?

Comment: Yo, si no te hace falta utilizar ninguna funcionalidad de la librería versión 26 que no tenga la 25, yo bajaría la versión de la librería, pero es una opinión personal. Cada smartphone (o casi) es un mundo, así que no soy muy partidario de utilizar "trucos", pero es una opinión personal, en temas de rendimiento o errores no te se decir

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano creo que será lo más acertado, ya que no me acaba de gustar como dices lo de tener que estar gastando "trucos", creo que bajaré la versión a 25. Gracias por los comentarios!!

Answer (score 2):

La libreria `com.android.support:design:26.+` requiere un mínimo del sdk 14 pero tu proyecto el sdk mínimo es de 9. Para funcionar tu proyecto debe de ser igual o mayor. Intenta buscando un compact de la librería para compatible con el nivel del sdk de tu proyecto.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Einer! he estado buscando y creo que poniendo la librería  25 serviría, voy a probar y luego te comento

Answer (score 0):

solo entra al archivo androidManifest.xml y borras la linea de codigo que vas a encontrar con el minskd version tal y pones esta  ahi estas forzando a que funcione si porque si

Comment: Esto es incorrecto, si se elimina el minSdk cual sería el mínimo con el que funcionaría la aplicación???